Error: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt
Estoy intentando que a la hora de consultar el balance de una wallet creada me devuelva la cantidad de weis comprados a través de la app. Tengo escrito
app.get("/getMyBalance/:address/:tokenAddress", async(req,res) => { 
try {
let userWallet = await walletFactorySC.methods.getWalletOf(req.params.address).call()
 if(userWallet === "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"){
res.status(400).send({error: "User not registered"}
return
        } else {
            const userWalletSC = new web3.eth.Contract(UserWallet.abi, userWallet) 
            const balance = await userWalletSC.methods.getTokenBalance(req.params.tokenAddress).call()
  res.status(200).send({Success: balance})
}

Y cuando utilizo esto me dice Do not know how to serialize a BigInt. He intentado pasar balance que es un BigInt a string con stringify y con .toLocaleString y con toString y no lo he conseguido. ¿alguien podría ayudarme? Muchas gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y en que linea te marca ese error???

¿Es JavaScript o TypeScript?
Este tipo BigInt es muy característico de TS y no de JS

@gbianchi. la línea que me da error es la de res.status(200).send({Success: balance}) y me marca que es el balance. Muchas gracias

@cardosource Es JavaScript. Muchas gracias

Javascript no contempla una forma nativa de convertir un BigInt a JSON, entonces no queda más que realizar una implementación personalizada
Un JSON se utiliza para comunicar sistemas, tienes el "Emisor" y el "Receptor", y ambos deben tener claridad de lo que se está enviando y recibiendo respectivamente (esto es común para lenguajes fuertemente tipados, cuando se envían objetos). BigInt no tiene un número máximo como lo tiene int o long, por lo que según el lenguaje y el número máximo que tu aplicación contempla (si es que existe) habrá distintas estrategias de conversión
Y es así como en la práctica, muchas veces se envía simplemente como String:


const balance = 1801439850948198200000000000000000000002n;
console.log(JSON.stringify({ Success: balance.toString()} ));



Por otro lado, un JSON (a diferencia de javascript) acepta número de largo ilimitado, es decir esto es válido:
{"Success":1801439850948198200000000000000000000002} //notar que el valor no tiene comillas

A mí me gusta más la idea de aprovechar esta característica
Nota: Como tu solo has puesto la etiqueta Javascript, supondré que tanto el Emisor como el Receptor utilizan este lenguaje
1) Emisor
Se necesita implementar una función toJSON al BigInt para indicarle como va a convertir a JSON


BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function () {
  return JSON.rawJSON(this.toString());
};

const objeto = {
  Success: 1801439850948198200000000000000000000002n
};

let json = JSON.stringify(objeto);
console.log(json);



Como se puede ver en el ejemplo anterior, no se agregan las comillas
2) Receptor
Aquí utilizaremos el segundo argumento de la función JSON.parse, el cual es una función que sobreescribe la transformación default que realiza javascript.
Y existen a lo menos 2 formas de afrontar esto
2.1) Por propiedad
Tú sabes que recibirás un objeto, el cual tiene una propiedad Success cuyo tipo es un BigInt


let json = '{"Success":1801439850948198200000000000000000000002}';

const parsedData = (key, value, context) => {
  if (key === "Success") {
    return BigInt(context.source);
  }
  return value;
};

const objeto_parseado = JSON.parse(json,parsedData);
console.log(objeto_parseado.Success.toString());



2.2) De forma genérica
La función parsedData tiene 3 argumentos:

key: el nombre de la propiedad
value: el valor procesado. Javascript convertirá el valor en un int, pero el número al ser demasiado largo dará un valor cualquiera
context.source:  El valor sin procesar en String

Entonces, podemos aprovechar que value != context.source cuando se trata de un BigInt, y de esta manera no necesitamos saber el nombre de la propiedad y nos servirá para cualquier objeto que contenga un BigInt


let json = '{"Success":1801439850948198200000000000000000000002}';


const parsedData = (key, value, context) => {
 if (typeof(value) === "number" && String(value) != context.source) {
    return BigInt(context.source);
  }
  return value;
};

const objeto_parseado = JSON.parse(json,parsedData);
console.log(objeto_parseado.Success.toString());




Simplemente lo he cambiado por res.status(200).send((JSON.stringify({ Success: balance.toString()} ))) y me ha funcionado. Muchísimas gracias @Yussef
